# Meteor performance when inserting/updating records

Tags: meteor

I have the following template:

```
<template name="datatable">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Path</th>
        <th>Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each entries}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{path}}</td>
          <td>{{avg}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

And entries is populated with:

```
Template.datatable.entries = ->
  Metrics.find( { metric: 'mean' }, { fields: { path: 1, avg: 1 }, sort: { avg: -1 }, limit: 10 })
```

Two problems:

1) When I refresh the page I can see the table rows changing very quickly until it displays the sorted list of 10. It's as if the client is receiving all the data and displaying and sorting it as it comes. I thought what I would get is that the client only receives 10 rows from the server.

2) When the server updates the collections the client freezes until the server is done updating.

How can I solve these two issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are partially right. The client is processing the data as it comes from the server. But it doesn't happen when you call `find`, but when `subscribe` is called. When you refresh the page, a new connection to the server is created as well as a new subscription. You can use subscription's `ready()` to wait for initial data to arrive. See [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe). If you don't want to handle the subscription state by yourself, `IronRouter` has a builtin way of waiting for the data to arrive (if using a router is not an overkill)
2. Sounds odd. The client should have no way of telling that the server is updating until the server send the data to the client. When this happens you should experience the behavior in #1. I would guess that either you are sending too much data to the client which takes time to sort, or that you are updating big chunks of the data. More details or a live example could help.

Comment: One way you might resolve the client freezing, might be to implement latency compensation. The DiscoverMeteor book has a chapter dedicated to it. 

The gist of the solution is to store the update collection method in a common directory i.e. anywhere not called client, server or public. Then when you call the update method it will run on the client and server. In the client code you can use this.isSimulation to determine if you're viewing client side (local collection) or data updated from the server.

Comment: Regarding #1, isn't the client supposed to only get the 10 documents it needs? (instead of the entire collection) If not then how are we supposed to work with large collections?

Comment: To get collection data, the client has to subscribe to a record set published by the server. To control which data is passed to the client, modify server-side `publish`. Latency compensation could make you application more responsive if the client initiates the db modifications.